# relational prolog and bit mask manipulations

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I am trying my hand at relational prolog. Part of my program needs to deal with bitmasks. It however seems that prolog code handles bit makes, such as to set a bit or clear a bit doesn't work relationally -- i.e. it only works in setting a bit, but not in the other direction, identifying what bit is set.

For example:

```
setbit(X, N, V) :-
    N1 #= 1<< N,
    V #= X \/ N1.
```

this code only work in one direction, where X and N are given and V is calculated. If one provides V and N, then X is not derived, but rather its left as an uninstantiated expression.

Does this mean that calculating with bit maps and masks is out of scope of relational prolog.

```
?- setbit(0,1,X).
X = 2.

?- setbit(X, 1, 2).
2#=X\/2.
```

the latter doesn't bind X to 0.

thank you,

Daniel

Edit: based on the comments below, the following code works very well:

```
setbit(X, N, V) :-
    X in 0..1,
    label([X]),
    N1 #= 1<< N,
    V #= X \/ N1.

clearbit(X, N, V) :-
    X in 0..1,
    label([X]),
    current_prolog_flag(max_tagged_integer, MTI),   
    N1 #= MTI /\ \(1<<N),
%   N1 #= 0xffffffffffffff /\ \(1<<N),
    V #= X /\ N1
```

Note, the current_prolog_flag -- it retrieves the maximum integer fitting into one word on the current machine architecture -- on 64 bit its 54 bits, the rest of the bits are used for housekeeping.

Comment: `X` bound to 0 isn't the only solution to `setbit(X, 1, 2)`.

Comment: Your new edit does not make much sense: You are no longer using the power of Prolog's constraints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not great at `clpfd`, but I think the problem here is that you haven't given X a *finite domain* or asked for its values to be enumerated. This works:

```
?- setbit(X, 1, 2), X in 0..1, label([X]).
X = 0 ;
false.
```

The second expression there, `X in 0..1` says you want X to be zero or one, and the third says, "give me the values X can obtain."

Comment: The problem with this answer I think is that for a general query of the form: `N = some_value, V = some_value, setbit(X, N, V), X in L..U, label([X]).` what should be the L,U (lower and Upper bounds) of X??

Comment: thank you.  including the addition into the setbit/2 worked very well.

Comment: @coder you'll have that information a-priori. The poster wound up using a fact about the machine architecture.

Answer (score 3):

From a given solution, you cannot conclude that it is the only solution. That is, from

```
?- setbit(0,1,X).
   X = 2.
```

you cannot conclude that

```
?- setbit(X, 1, 2).
```

has `X = 0` as the **only** solution. In fact, there is another solution, namely

```
?- setbit(2, 1, 2).
   true.
```

Ideally, all constraints would maintain domain-consistency.  In this ideal world we would have:

```
?- setbit(X, 1, 2).
   X in 0\/2,           % idealiter
   2#=X\/2.
```

instead of

```
?- setbit(X, 1, 2).      
   2#=X\/2.             % realiter
```

But first of all, let us realize that both answers are correct! The second answer says precisely the same as the ideal one.  However, finding a concrete solution may be more costly in the second case. In particular, since the following query has an answer:

```
?- setbit(X, 1, 2), X #> 2.
   X in 3..sup,
   2#=X\/2.             % inconsistency
```

This answer reads like the notice of winning a lottery ticket you never heard of:

> Yes, congratulation! There is a solution, <sub><sup><sup>provided all this fine print, this X in 3..sup, 2#=/2 has a solution, otherwise it does not have any solution. So don't complain, we told you so.</sup></sup></sub>

That is, an answer may very well contain exactly zero solutions. To be absolutely sure about a solution, you have to eliminate all constraints. The easiest way to do so, is using `labeling/2`. **However**, `labeling/2` is defined only for finite domains (that's where the FD in CLPFD stems from). But in this case `X` is not constrained to a finite domain - would that be the case, we would have an extra constraint like `X in 0..2`.

The degree of consistency in clpfd-systems heavily depends on the actual use cases. After all, full consistency is undecidable. So there will always be cases where we would expect a more precise outcome. It is rather a question of tradeoffs for both run- and development time. Should you have convincing use cases contact the system developer.

In this particular case, you are probably better off using modulo arithmetics and addition.